# Unable Create Project on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I try to create project using Laravel 8. But it is failed, my PHP version 8.1.0 and my composer version 2.1.6

[image]

Comment: PHP 8.1 is still in beta so I suggest either using a development version of Laravel with it or use an officially released PHP version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please explain more when you are getting that error, it seems to me from the screenshot its not coming while creating the laravel project.

Are you using the below command to create project?

`composer create-project laravel/laravel projectname`